# Alternative to NSJSONSerialization for 10.6?

Tags: json, osx-snow-leopard

Working on adding support for Snow Leopard here for a Mac app that I have on the MAS, and the only thing I've found so far that I need to replace is my reliance on NSJSONSerialization.

So what's a good library for JSON parsing under Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem sometime ago, there are lots of parsers out there, but my favourite (performance wise) is [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)

Only downside is it's not ARC compatible, but you can either Disable ARC for the JSONKit Source file OR build it as a Universal Framework, You'll find that in one of the pull requests.